How to change the value of a DropdownButtonFormField with SetState in flutter
I have a DropdownButtonFormField and want to change the selected value with setState executed from another element. This is my dropdown field:
selectedNumber = "5"; 

DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    hint: Text(selectedNumber != "Select"
        ? selectedNumber
        : "Select",                            
    ),
    //value: "",
    items: _durationList.map((value) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: new Text(value),
        );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
            selectedNumber = value!;
            _selectedNumberController.text = value;
        });
    },
),

This is my other element with setState that should supposedly change the value in the DropdownButtonFormField :
setState(() {
    selectedNumber = "Select";
    _selectedNumberController.text = "";
});

This setState however, works only when no item was selected from the dropdown, i.e. after the build method the default selectedNumber is 5.
When triggered the setState updates the selectedNumber and the value in the dropdown is changed to Select.
However, if I choose a value from the dropdown list after the build method, i.e. I change the value from 5 to 10 for example, the setState does not change the dropdown field value.
Any suggestion how to accomplish this?

I think you are on the right track. I need a little more code to say for sure, but my guess off the cuff is that it is a hierarchy issue. setState only works for children of the widget in which it is called. This video explains this concept pretty well towards the end: https://youtu.be/nDwH7iskkHA?si=1Z7osnDnSKfGrXi3

In this code, you have two widgets that can modify the selectedNumber value.
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          hint: Text(selectedNumber ?? 'Select'),
          value: selectedNumber,
          items: _durationList.map((value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedNumber = value;
            });
          },
        ),
IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            selectedNumber = null;
          }),
          icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
        ),

Within your main widget class, you should define the default value for selectedNumber, which should be null or one element of your _durationList list for example
late String? selectedNumber = null;

